# html newsletter not working properly in the email

Tags: html, newsletter

hi i have the simple banner to send in the email as signature in email. but this is not working. i am sending from hotmail and i add the html code in signature. but links are not working also sometime layout is disturbing so much. here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body style="margin:0; padding:0;">
<table style="margin:0; padding:0;"><tr style="margin:0; padding:0;"><td style="margin:0;" background="http://work.zatechno.com/artzone/background.png" bgcolor="#7bceeb" width="1232" height="195" valign="top">
          <!--[if gte mso 9]>
          <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:1232px;height:196px;">
            <v:fill type="tile" src="http://work.zatechno.com/artzone/background.png" color="#7bceeb" />
            <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
          <![endif]--><div style="float:left; margin:100px 0 0 470px; padding:0; position:relative; width:504px; height:94px;">
        <div style="float:left; width:242px; height:100%; position:relative">
            <a href="#" style="float:left; margin:12px 0 0 7px;"><img src="http://work.zatechno.com/artzone/location.png" alt="" style="float:left" /></a>
            <div style="clear:both; width:100%; height:1px; float:left"></div>
            <a href="#" style="float:left; margin:8px 0 0 4px;"><img src="http://work.zatechno.com/artzone/website.png" alt="" style="float:left" /></a>
            <div style="clear:both; width:100%; height:1px; float:left"></div>
            <a href="#" style="float:left; margin:12px 0 0 6px;"><img src="http://work.zatechno.com/artzone/email.png" alt="" style="float:left" /></a>
        </div>

        <div style="float:right; width:255px; height:100%; position:relative">
            <a href="#" style="float:left; margin:12px 0 0 9px;"><img src="http://work.zatechno.com/artzone/phone.png" alt="" style="float:left" /></a>
            <div style="clear:both; width:100%; height:1px; float:left"></div>
            <a href="#" style="float:left; margin:10px 0 0 6px;"><img src="http://work.zatechno.com/artzone/social.png" alt="" style="float:left" /></a>
            <div style="clear:both; width:100%; height:1px; float:left"></div>
            <a href="#" style="float:left; margin:12px 0 0 42px; padding:0;"><img src="http://work.zatechno.com/artzone/youtube.png" alt="" /></a>
            <a href="#" style="float:left; margin:12px 0 0 21px; padding:0;"><img src="http://work.zatechno.com/artzone/facebook.png" alt="" /></a>
            <a href="#" style="float:left; margin:11px 0 0 20px; padding:0;"><img src="http://work.zatechno.com/artzone/twitter.png" alt="" /></a>
            <a href="#" style="float:left; margin:11px 0 0 21px; padding:0;"><img src="http://work.zatechno.com/artzone/linkedin.png" alt="" /></a>
            <a href="#" style="float:left; margin:12px 0 0 23px; padding:0;"><img src="http://work.zatechno.com/artzone/instagram.png" alt="" /></a>
        </div>

    </div>
          <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            </v:textbox>
          </v:rect>
          <![endif]--></td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried the JSFiddle for your HTML code and it worked perfectly.

Comment: yes in browser it works fine. but not working for me in emails. or i am wrong testing.

Comment: It could be the Hotmail which may be overwriting your CSS properties. Can't tell for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Which email agents is failing in and how? Maybe you can add a screengrab or two. I'm afraid you need to default to table based layout. html rendering capabilities of email agents can be rather limited and your best bet is keeping it as simple as possible.

Comment: can we add newsletter in the signature ? with links. because when i send from php using mail function it works fine.